# Can I load puzzles manually in Shortyz without an internet connection?

Tags: shortyz

[Shortyz](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=crossword&fdid=com.totsp.crossword.shortyz) (a crossword app for Android) seems to be designed to download puzzles.   My device doesn't connect to the internet.   Is there a way to manually load puzzles?   (ie, By putting .puz files in a directory on the SD card)

(It is available through F-Droid, linked above or the Market/Play, link as follows:)

 https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.totsp.crossword.shortyz

Comment: Update:   I tried, and it half works.   If I browse to a puzzle file (.puz format works, .jpz doesn't) with a file manager, I can open it with Shortyz.   It seems to work pretty well, and even saves my progress - but I can't browse from within Shortyz, and even after loading a puzzle, it doesn't show up in the list in the Shortyz menu.   So, workable, but I'm still leaving this open as 'half-solved'; it would be nice to know how to get the puzzles to show up in the list, or to have confirmation that it can't be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.   Shortyz creates a directory on the SD card called 'crosswords'.

('Duh', right?   I did have another program on the device that's actually called 'Crosswords', so maybe I'm not a complete idiot .. just a partial one).

Anyway, dropping my '.puz' files in that directory makes them show up in Shortyz.   There's also a sub-directory called 'archives' that - you guessed it - makes them show up in the 'archives' list.   Interestingly, I copied a .puz from the directory I had been using *without* copying the .shortyz file (which I assume stores progress), and Shortyz seems to find the .shortyz file, and show my progress.

It would be nice if I could make my own directories to organize a big pile of puzzles (and have Shortyz recognize the dirs), and/or if I could browse for other directories from within the program - but that's not within the scope of this question.   Maybe I'll submit a feature request or (gasp) submit a patch (yay, FOSS).